# How do I gitignore a word document?

Tags: git, gitignore

For example, I have a word document titled `results.docx` inside of the directory `research`. How would I gitignore this word document from the `research` directory?

Comment: Did you try adding it to .gitignore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove all files of **.docx** use below

```
*.docx
```

if you want to ignore a specific file under a specific folder/directory then use:

```
folder_name/results.docx
```

inside .gitignore file.

Comment: I second this! This will ignore all the occurences of `.docx` files in your working directory.
If you want to ignore `.docx` specific to a folder, just use `folder_name/*.docx`(_where the `folder_name`'s path is relative to your working directory_)